# Unable to load CSS with filter: filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicI

Tags: webpack, css-loader

I'm trying to perfectly working CSS file into js module. Unfortunately css-loader have problem with this part:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color=#466496)
```

I'm receiving CssSyntaxError after `progid`. Howto bypass this error?

Comment: I wonder if it makes sense to support IE 6/7 browsers.

Comment: It works, I don't want edit minified working css files.

Comment: I just built a test code from `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cedce7', endColorstr='#596a72',GradientType=0 );` and everything compiles well but changes to your code
`Filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage (rotation = 1) progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma (color = # 466496)`
An error appears - no semicolon, apparently only one declaration is possible. However, without changing the file can not do :)